# Input file not found in docker command on windows

Tags: docker, osrm

Complete docker noob here, i installed docker desktop on windows - Trying to follow the commands on [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend)  to setup OSRM backend on my machine. i've downloaded the dataset for india(india-latest.osm.pbf) to D:/docker
and am running the commands from that location

```
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/india-latest.osm.pbf
```

fails with

> [error] Input file /data/india-latest.osm.pbf not found!

i just don't understand WHY it doesn't work. according to osrm documentation of the docker command -

> The file /data/india-latest.osm.pbf inside the container is referring
>   to "${PWD}/india-latest.osm.pbf" on the host.

but it's not the case,i am running from d:/docker so it should find india-latest.osm.pbf no problem. This is really really confusing to me even though it must be so basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was due to a bug in docker https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1712

when you change password it silently fails for commands that access the host filesystem on windows until you reauthenticate

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 user,

I found and article to use %cd% instead of ${PWD} and it worked for me, here the link: https://michaelbrooks.co.uk/windows-version-of-linuxs-pwd/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34130378)